# On IOS, I need to prevent users going from one window to another if the fields are not correct

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication

I build an app that requires a login on the first page.

I am having trouble preventing users from advancing to the next screen, even if they submit an incorrect login field. I would appreciate any insight into this issue, as well as some sample codes if possible.

Comment: A little code never killed nobody. Please, we ask you to show us your `function`s, `data model`s or whatever you have in mind so far. For help, check out [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're sending your users to other screens using Storyboard segues. Remove the segue you've added to your button and create a custom segue.

Custom segues can be created by opening your storyboard and dragging from one `ViewController` to another.
Create a custom segue with an identifier and create a function as follows:

```
if ([loginTextField.text length] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Show incorrect field alert.");
    return;
}

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can put whatever checks you need in there, not just length - and you probably want to give some user feedback rather than just the NSLog - an alert view or update a status label somewhere on your login screen

Comment: @Russell: Exactly! ^

Answer (score 0):

In place where you check whether to push another controller you can user `guard` statement like this:

```
guard true else { //replace true with your own validation
    return
}

//perform segue here
//present controller manually here
//manage your views here
//do whatever you wish here
```